# Redefining a function by supplying some of its arguments

Tags: python

let's suppose there is a function like below:

```
def func(arg1, args2):
    # do sth using arg1 and arg2
```

In the runtime, I would like to keep use some value for `args2` which we can't know when defining the `func`.

So what I would like to do is:

```
func_simpler = func(, args2=some_value_for_arg2)
func_simpler(some_value_for_arg1) # actual usage
```

Any idea on it? I know that there is a walk-around such as defining `func` better, but I seek for a solution more like `func_simpler` thing.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you aware of ``functools.partial``?

Comment: does this solve `def func(arg1, args2=None):`

Comment: @MisterMiyagi yeah I was trying something like the codes of functools.partial you introduced above, but it seemed a bit confusing. But I just came up with another solution :) I will specify it in the answer below

Comment: @jonrsharpe same answer with MisterMiyagi

Comment: def func(arg1, args2=Default _value):

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `lambda` in python

**Original function**

```
def func(arg1, arg2):
```

**Then you get the value you want as default for arg2 and define simple_func**

```
simple_func = lambda arg1 : func(arg1, arg2=new_default)
```

**Now you can run simple_func**

```
simple_func("abc") #"abc" = value for arg1
```

Hope I could help you

Comment: Wow this is the answer that I've looked for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to solve this myself and I found a not-bad solution:

```
def func(a, b):
    print(a, ": variable given everytime the model is used")
    print(b, ": variable given when the model is defined")
enter code here
def model(b):
    def model_deliver(a):
        func(a, b)
    return model_deliver
s = model(20)
s(12) #prints result as below
# 12 : variable given everytime the model is used
# 20 : variable given when the model is defined
```

Comment: Nice one! This is basically like using lambda!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

def func(arg1, arg2):
    print(f'got {arg1!r} and {arg2!r}')

simple_func = partial(func, arg2='something')
simple_func("value of arg1")
# got 'value of arg1' and 'something'
```

Using [`partial` produces an object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#partial-objects) which has various advantages over using a wrapper function:

- If the initial function and its arguments can be `pickle`d, the `partial` object can be `pickle`d as well.
- The `repr`/`str` of a `partial` object shows the initial function information.
- Repeated application of `partial` is efficient, as it flattens the wrappers.
- The function and its partially applied arguments can be inspected.

Note that if you want to partially apply arguments of a method, use [`functools.partialmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partialmethod) instead.

Comment: Awesome answer! Can I ask what is the exact meaning of pickle-able?

Comment: [``pickle``](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) is the default module to serialise/deserialise (aka "store/load") Python objects. It is used behind the scenes in many cases, e.g. ``multiprocessing`` pickles objects to send them between processes. Due to the way ``pickle`` works, certain objects such as ``lambda`` functions cannot be pickled.